# CSS causing red frame around lightbox image - how to remove?

Tags: css, lightbox

On my webpage im using EIT Lightbox for displaying pictures, its a .NET control which nicely wraps the Javascript lightbox, so I don't have to code a single line of Javascript. But since I upgraded to IE 8, all the pictures in the lightbox show with a fat red frame. For an example, please see http://www.qaz.dk/NewestPicturesAlbum.aspx.

How can I remove the red frame?

Comment: It does it in Chrome and Firefox too.

Comment: Edited the question to address the actual issue (nothing to do with .NET)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got #hoverNav a{ outline: red solid 10px;} in lightbox.css. Remove to fix.